# Why does the sort function change the order of same values?

Tags: c++, sorting, programming-languages

I have vector of type `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`. I am simply trying to arrange it in descending order (by using the first int value of `std::pair` objects) while keeping it stable so that equal numbers remain in the order they were inserted.

Fe:
If I have  :. 5 , 3a , 4  ,3b , 6
I want it be ordered : 6, 5, 4, 3a, 3b

But it doesn't seem to work fine.  Sort function sorts it in increasing order. So what I am trying to do is to sort and then take them in reverse order. But then I get same values in reversed order too which isn't stable and not good for me.  So I tried reversing the whole vector first, and only then sort it and later take them in reverse order but I don't know why it doesn't work?
It looks like the sort function changes it in order of insertion even if I reverse the vector first.

Anyways how am I achieving my goal.  An decreasingly ordered vector while keeping it stable.

EDIT: To all the people saying to use stable sort. This doesn't help either. I tried it.  And my question isn't about just a stable order but a bout a descending order and yet stable. Non of them achieve it.

Comment: `std::sort` does not guarantee that the relative order of values that compare as equal will be preserved. If you need to preserve the order of values, you must include all that logic in your sort comparator function. The End.

Comment: There is in fact a `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: You should read the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). There you can find all information: `std::sort` is not stable and `std::stable_sort` is stable

Comment: Stable sort doesn't help. You didn't read the question properly. I wasn't asking about a stable ascending order but about a decending order and stable

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows that `stable_sort` "doesn't work".  You are describing what you have, but descriptions are not truth -- let's see the actual code sample.

Comment: I am talking specifically about decending order in vector pair

Comment: @bilanush -- You were asked to post the code, but you have yet to do so.  We are disputing your claim that `stable_sort` doesn't work, and the issue is actually "user error".

Comment: @bilanush - I'm getting the impression that you want the descending stable sort to reverse the order of equal elements. In that case, you would need to reverse the array (or vector) first, then use std::stable_sort(). You could also create an array of pointers to the pairs, then use a lambda compare that compares pointers if two pairs are equal, in which case you can control the ordering even with std:sort.

Comment: @rcgldr you got impression wrong, OP wants descending order, but `std::sort()` sorts in ascending order, so instead of providing proper comparator OP decides to reverse elements in vector after sort - hense loosing order of equal elements.

Comment: I never meant to say stable sort doesn't work. It just doesn't work when trying to do my trick.  My trick is to first reverse the vector. Then sort or stable sort it and then take vector in reverse again. Why I don't get a decending stable vector. I do get it in decending order but it isn't stable. Why?

Comment: @bilanush - in that case, use std::stable_sort() with a user specified compare function to make it a descending sort, and don't bother reversing the vector before or after.

Comment: @bilanush -- Because your "trick" is not how stable sorting is done.  If it were that easy, wouldn't `std::stable_sort` use the same trick?  Why are you not simply using a comparison functor?

Comment: @bilanush we could not know why your trick does not work without [mcve]. But proper answer - do not use this trick, but use `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort` properly

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why ??  In logic it's very simple.  I an reversing it. Then I am simply asking to do a normal sort while keeping same values unchanged. Then I want to reverse it again. That's all what I am asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you comparing elements because "3a" is not the same as "3b" unless you create some custom comparator that makes them compare the same. Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Tip: `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: @bilanush *I an reversing it* -- Again, a description.  We have no idea when you say `reversing it` what you are really doing.  Said again, a description does not tell the truth.  Show the code -- only the code is the truth.  What if you finally show the code, and one of us points out your bug or oversight that you thought you never had?

Comment: It's a good of thaosands of lines. I have to copy alot in order to show you it isn't keeping it stable.  Trust me it isn't.  What's so complex about what I do? I reversing the vector then sorting it in acsending order and then reversing it again.  I can't do any better

Comment: @bilanush what's wrong with my answer? It does exactly what you asked for. Reverses the order and preserves the original order for equal elements.

Comment: And it yealds it in decending order?

Comment: @bilanush *It's a good of thaosands of lines* -- You mean to reverse and sort is thousands of lines??  `std::reverse`, `std::sort`??  All that indicates is that your code is much more than what you're describing, and chances are there are bugs in these "thousands of lines".  What's difficult about creating a simple vector of values, and calling 3 or 4 functions to demonstrate this error you're claiming?  The help you're getting here is working on code that works.  What you're working with is some mysterious large code base, and we have no idea if there are bugs or not.

Comment: *Trust me it isn't.* -- No, it doesn't work that way here.  We can't work on "trust".  The reason is that if we "trust", and try to come up with the magic code ourselves to see if `std::stable_sort` is broken or whatever you're claiming, we end up wasting our time when it is your code that is at fault.  Look at the answers already given -- work that could be potentially gone to answering other questions here.  That's why we need to see the code from *you*, not from us.

Comment: It's nothing to do with my code because I can see if it gets in reverse order in acsending order or increasing order.   I debugged it and I see the (stable) sort function the minute I try sorting my vector in decending order gives me same values with order alerted .  Bottom line I am asking how to do decending order while keeping it stable.

Comment: *t's nothing to do with my code because I can see* -- I give up.  *You* can see, but we can't see anything.

Comment: If you can't then don't answer. I am not begging ppl who don't want to answer to answer. This is a question for ppl who can deal with it and answer with the limited yet best information I could provide.  Nobody forces you to answer.

Comment: @bilanush -- I am making a valiant attempt of helping you *not* get downvoted for this question and future questions.  I am giving advice to you -- also, the comment section is for comments, not answers, so I am commenting.  The answer you did accept -- look at the last section of code -- that is all we would have liked from you.  A simple program that takes a vector, attempts to sort it, and then work from there as to how to address the problem, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: I told you exactly why I couldn't do it.   AndI didn't ask about a specific code. I asked a theoretical question about reversing a vector sorting it and reversing again. Expected decreasingly ordered vector and stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)
>
> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. **The
>   order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.**

Thus, the order of equal elements might or might not change. What you are looking for is [std::stable_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. **The
>   order of equivalent elements is guaranteed to be preserved.**

If you want to stable sort the vector in descending order, one of your options is using [rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend). The order will be reversed; here's an example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class A {
 public:
  A(int d = 0, const std::string& n = "a"): data(d), name(n) {}
  friend bool operator< (const A& par1, const A& par2) {
    return par1.data < par2.data;
  }
  A& operator= (const A& other) {
    data = other.getData();
    name = other.getName();
    return *this;
  }
  std::string getName() const {
    return name;
  }

  int getData() const {
    return data;
  }

 private:
  int data = 0;
  std::string name;
};

int main()
{
  A a(7, "a"), b(2, "b"), c(3, "c"), d(2, "d"), e(3, "e"), f(6, "f");
  std::vector<A> iv {a, b, c, d, e, f};
  std::stable_sort(iv.rbegin(), iv.rend());

  for (const auto e : iv) {
    std::cout << e.getName() << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a f c e b d
```

As can be seen the order is preserved for equal elements, and the vector is sorted in reverse order.

Another option is using [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater). It is defined in the `<functional>` header, and you will need [operator>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison). Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


class A {
 public:
  A(int d = 0, const std::string& n = "a"): data(d), name(n) {}
  friend bool operator< (const A& par1, const A& par2) {
    return par1.data < par2.data;
  }
  friend bool operator> (const A& par1, const A& par2) {
    return par1.data > par2.data;
  }
  A& operator= (const A& other) {
    data = other.getData();
    name = other.getName();
    return *this;
  }
  std::string getName() const {
    return name;
  }

  int getData() const {
    return data;
  }

 private:
  int data = 0;
  std::string name;
};

int main()
{
  A a(7, "a"), b(2, "b"), c(3, "c"), d(2, "d"), e(3, "e"), f(6, "f");
  std::vector<A> iv {a, b, c, d, e, f};
  std::stable_sort(iv.begin(), iv.end(), std::greater<A>());

  for (const auto e : iv) {
    std::cout << e.getName() << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a f c e b d
```

## Edit:

If you want to reverse and stable sort an object of type `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` based on the first element (as seems to be the case here), you may use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

using pis = std::pair<int, std::string>;


int main()
{
  pis a{5, "a"}, b{3, "b"}, c{4, "c"}, d{3, "d"}, e{3, "e"};
  std::vector<pis> iv {a, b, c, d, e};
  std::stable_sort(iv.begin(), iv.end(), [](const pis p1, const pis p2) {return p1.first > p2.first;});




  for (const auto e : iv) {
    std::cout << e.second << "(" << e.first << ")" << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a(5) c(4) b(3) d(3) e(3)
```

**Highlights**
1. Note that `pis` is a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) for `std::pair<int, std::string>`
2. Use of `>` instead of `<` in the lambda is what causes the vector to be reversed.

Comment: Stable sort doesn't help. You didn't read the question properly. I wasn't asking about a stable ascending order but about a decending order and stable

Comment: @bilanush Added a way to reverse the ordering while sorting stably

Comment: In your code how you can check if it is stable?

Comment: This is not good at all. It's just sorting and reversing. Why would it be stable?

Comment: @bilanush it is stable because I used `std::stable_sort`. See the new code example

Comment: No I don't know what you posted here.  I am asking about a specific question. Meaning, reversing the vector then sorting it in acsending order and reversing again.  Doesn't work

Comment: I tried both of your options and they don't work. As I am using pair vectors it keeps flipping the order of same values.

Comment: @bilanush added an example doing just that. You may ask for further clarification

Comment: @bilanush what is a pair vector? A vector of pairs? Can you add some of your code to the question so it will be more clear what you are asking for

Comment: I like your answer now that I read it. It's very neat and really achieves what I asked for. But I tried both methods on my pair vector sorting by first element and it doesn't work.

Comment: @bilanush is your *pair vector*'s type `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`?

Comment: No. It's <int, string>

Comment: But sort by default works on the int so your 'greater' function should work here.  But I didn't implement operators overloadings because it's int.  Everything runs and well but I don't get a stable vector for the hells of me

Comment: @bilanush No. Sort by default uses [lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) for `std::pair`

Comment: I thought I read it works on the first element.

Comment: I thought I read it works on the first element.  By default.

Comment: If you are right.  Then how can I use a built in function to sort by the first int value? Thank alot.

Comment: I think I got it right already thank.

Comment: Accepted and voted

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the sort function change the order of same values?

Because [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for `std::sort()` says so:

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. **The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.**

emphasis is mine. If you need to preserve order use [`std::stable_sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. **The order of equivalent elements is guaranteed to be preserved.**

Note:

> Sort function sorts it in increasing order. So what I am trying to do is to sort and then take them in reverse order.

This is a wrong approach - you loose order not because `std::stable_sort()` "does not work" but because you reverse your vector after the sort, just use `std::stable_sort()` which accepts custom comparator and provide one (best option using lambda) which sorts it in descending order. Then `std::stable_sort()` would preserve order of your equal elements and you do not need to reverse your vector.

Comment: Stable sort doesn't help.  You didn't read the question properly. I wasn't asking about a stable ascending order but about a decending order and stable.

Comment: @bilanush it does indeed, ascending or descending order depends on comparator, stable sort will keep order of elements which comparator treats as equal.

Comment: I tried and it didn't help.  Note, I am using a pair vector.

Comment: Then you tried wrong and you should create a question with example data and code you tried, expected outcome and what you got. If you have pair and need first element in descending order but second in ascending write proper comparator, again create a question with [mcve] and data sample

Comment: @bilanush see addition to my answer, you just doing sorting wrong.

Comment: So read my question carefully again.  I said I am reversing the whole vector first. Then sorting(even with stable sort) it in acsending order. And then taking values in reverse.  Why doesn't it work? I expect it to be sorted in decending order.

Comment: @bilanush if you need descending order why do you sort it in ascending order? Add [mcve] with a data sample and expected outcome instead, your description is convoluted and confusing -  2 reverses, sorting etc. Or better create another question.